# live() click not work proper in javscaript

Tags: javascript, function

this is my final.xml file:-

```
<root>
    <child1 entity_id = "1" value= "Asia">
        <child2 entity_id = "2" value = "india">
            <child3 entity_id = "3" value = "Gujarat">
                <child5 entity_id = "5" value ="Rajkot"></child5>
            </child3>
            <child4 entity_id = "4" value = "Rajshthan">
                <child6 entity_id = "6" value = "Ajmer"></child6>
            </child4>
        </child2>
    </child1>
</root>
```

this is my html code:-

```
<body>
    <div id="loader">
        <span id='update-target'>Click here to load value</span>
    </div>

    <div id="firstLevelChild"></div>

    <div id="path"><span class="tagit-new"></span></div>
</body>
```

this is my script:-

```
<script>
data = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "final.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                data = xml;
                ul = $("<ul></ul>");
                $(xml).find('child1').each(function(){
                    var value_text = $(this).attr('value');
                    var id = $(this).attr('entity_id');
                    li = $("<li id='" + id + "'></li>");
                    li.html(value_text);
                    ul.append(li);
                    $(this).unbind('click');

                });       //close each(      
                ul.appendTo('#firstLevelChild');
            }
        }); //close $.ajax(
    }); //close click(

    $(document).on("click", "li", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        loadChild($(this).attr("id"), event);
        return false;
    });
});
$("#firstLevelChild ul li").live("click", function(){
    $("#path .tagit-new").html($(this).html());
    a = $("<a class=\"close\">x</a>\n");
    $(".tagit-new").append(a);

$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".tagit-new").html('');
});
});
function loadChild(id) {
    var obj = $("#firstLevelChild #" + id);

    if(obj.data("loaded") == null) {
        ul = "<ul>";
        var path = (id == 0) ? "root" : "[entity_id='" + id + "']";

        // Only if it contains children
        if( $(data).find(path).children().length > 0) {
            $("li").show();
        }

        $(data).find(path).children().each(function(){
            var value_text = $(this).attr('value');
            var id = $(this).attr('entity_id');
            ul += "<li id='" + id + "'>" + value_text + "</li>";
        });

        ul += "</ul>";
        obj.append(ul);
       obj.data("loaded", true);
    } else {
        $("#" + id + " ul").remove();
        obj.data("loaded", null);
    }
}
</script>
```

this is js file i use:-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

here i am try to get Region form the xml file.
find chil1 attribute value from the xml file. and then set click on it. click on it display there child like:-
click on `Asia` display there child.
tree wise like:-

```
Asia 
    India
```

and click on `India`

```
Asia 
    India
         Gujarat
         Rajshthan
```

and click on Gujarat

```
Asia
    India
         Gujarat
                Rajkot
         Rajshthan
```

now i am use `live()` to append clicked value in `<span>` 
now problem is when i am click on first time its display in span proper.
 
but second time click on them its display there child. something like this type:-
Asia
   India
        Gujarat
              Rajkot
        Rajshthan
last clicked value is Rajkot so in my span display something like this type:-
`<div id="path"><span class="tagit-new">`**Rajkot**`</span></div>`
now i am click on there parent then its display 
`<div id="path"><span class="tagit-new">`**Gujarat Rajkot**`</span></div>`
as my logic its only display clicked text. **Gujurat**
why i am getting this porblem please review my code and help me to solve this.
thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing `$(this).unbind('click');` on an XML node that hasn't been added to DOM yet?

Comment: unbind for last child... but not this problem...

Comment: @Jack here is some problem in obj.append(ul); here i am using obj.after(ul); then its work perfect but not minimize list at second time click.

Answer (score 2):

`live()` has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. You are using 1.8.3. Use `on` instead. See [this](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods:
>
> ```
> $(selector).live(events, data, handler); // jQuery 1.3+
> $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler); // jQuery 1.4.3+
> $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler); // jQuery 1.7+
> ```

Comment: @alex23 you should quote the relevant parts here. As such, it's a link-only answer. Link-only answers are not welcome here.

Comment: i am using on() then not append value in my `<span>`

Comment: "problem is when i am click on first time its display in span proper. " - if this was a `.live()` deprecation problem, why does it work on the first click? Not saying that `.live()` should be used btw.

Comment: here is some problem in `obj.append(ul);` here i am using `obj.after(ul);` then its work perfect but not minimize list at second time click...